# Translate PHP JSON in Flutter

Tags: php, json, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I have flutter app, which retrieves data from a JSON request using PHP code. How can I translate lines in php in flutter to multilingual. I would need to translate the lines in the "Title" field in the PHP file. Maybe somebody know how to make translate.
If I translate other strings I add end off ".tr". But how to do it when "Title" is fetched by JSON request?

PHP Code

```
<?php
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/filemanager/evconfing.php';
require dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/filemanager/event.php';
header('Content-type: text/json');
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if ($data['orag_id'] == '') {
    $returnArr = array(
        "ResponseCode" => "401",
        "Result" => "false",
        "ResponseMsg" => "Something Went Wrong!"
    );
} else {
    $orag_id               = $data['orag_id'];
    $total_event           = $evmulti->query("select * from tbl_event where sponsore_id=" . $orag_id . " and event_status ='Pending'")->num_rows;
    $eventlist = $evmulti->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) as event_id FROM `tbl_event` WHERE sponsore_id=".$orag_id." and (event_status='Completed' or event_status='Cancelled')")->fetch_assoc();
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    $total_today = $evmulti->query("select * from tbl_event where sponsore_id=".$orag_id." and event_status ='Pending' and sdate='".$date."'")->num_rows;
    $upcoming_event = $evmulti->query("select * from tbl_event where sponsore_id=".$orag_id." and event_status ='Pending' and sdate >'".$date."'")->num_rows;
    $past_event = $evmulti->query("select * from tbl_event where sponsore_id=".$orag_id." and (event_status ='Completed' or event_status ='Cancelled')")->num_rows;
    $event_id = empty($eventlist['event_id']) ? 0 : $eventlist['event_id'];
    $total_cover_image     = $evmulti->query("select * from tbl_cover where sponsore_id=" . $orag_id . " and eid NOT IN (".$event_id.")")->num_rows;
    $total_type_price      = $evmulti->query("select * from tbl_type_price where sponsore_id=" . $orag_id . " and event_id NOT IN (".$event_id.")")->num_rows;
    $total_gallery         = $evmulti->query("select * from tbl_gallery where sponsore_id=" . $orag_id . " and eid NOT IN (".$event_id.")")->num_rows;
    $total_artist          = $evmulti->query("select * from tbl_artist where sponsore_id=" . $orag_id . " and eid NOT IN (".$event_id.")")->num_rows;
    $total_coupon          = $evmulti->query("select * from tbl_coupon where sponsore_id=" . $orag_id . "")->num_rows;
    $t                     = $evmulti->query("select sum(`total_ticket`) as totaltic from tbl_ticket where sponsore_id=" . $orag_id . " and ticket_type!='Cancelled'")->fetch_assoc();
    $total_ticket_sale     = (empty($t['totaltic'])) ? "0" : $t['totaltic'];
    $total_earn            = $evmulti->query("select sum((subtotal-cou_amt) - ((subtotal-cou_amt) * commission/100)) as total_amt from tbl_ticket where sponsore_id=" . $orag_id . " and ticket_type ='Completed'")->fetch_assoc();
    $total_earns           = empty($total_earn['total_amt']) ? "0" : number_format((float) ($total_earn['total_amt']), 2, '.', '');
    
    $total_payout          = $evmulti->query("select sum(amt) as total_payout from payout_setting where owner_id=" . $orag_id . "")->fetch_assoc();
    $receive_payout        = empty($total_payout['total_payout']) ? "0" : number_format((float) ($total_payout['total_payout']), 2, '.', '');
    $final_earn            = number_format((float) ($total_earns) - $receive_payout, 2, '.', '');
    $papi                  = array(
        array( //0
            "title" => "My Events",
            "report_data" => $total_event,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/1total_event.png'
        ),
        array( //1
            "title" => "Today Events",
            "report_data" => $total_today,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/2todayevent.png'
        ),
        array( //7
            "title" => "Artists",
            "report_data" => $total_artist,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/8artist.png'
        ),
        array( //2
            "title" => "Coming Events",
            "report_data" => $upcoming_event,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/3upcoming_event.png'
        ),
        array( //4
            "title" => "Event Tickets",
            "report_data" => $total_type_price,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/5type_price.png'
        ),
        array( //3
            "title" => "Past Events",
            "report_data" => $past_event,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/4past_event.png'
        ),
        array( //6
            "title" => "Cover Images",
            "report_data" => $total_cover_image,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/7cover_image.png'
        ),
        array( //5
            "title" => "Coupons",
            "report_data" => $total_coupon,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/6coupon.png'
        ),
        array( //8
            "title" => "Gallery Images",
            "report_data" => $total_gallery,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/9gallery.png'
        ),
        //array( //9
        //    "title" => "Ticket Sales",
        //    "report_data" => $total_ticket_sale,
        //    "url" => 'images/dashboard/10ticketsales.png'
        //),
        array( //10
            "title" => "Total Earning",
            "report_data" => $total_earns,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/11earning.png'
        ),
        array( //11
            "title" => "Payout",
            "report_data" => $receive_payout,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/12payout.png'
        ),
        array( //12
            "title" => "Account Balance",
            "report_data" => $final_earn,
            "url" => 'images/dashboard/13afterpayout.png'
        )
    );
    
    $returnArr = array(
        "ResponseCode" => "200",
        "Result" => "true",
        "ResponseMsg" => "Report List Get Successfully!!!",
        "report_data" => $papi,
        "withdraw_limit" => $set['pstore']
    );
    
}
echo json_encode($returnArr);
?>
```

Flutter file "main.dart"

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, duplicate_ignore

import 'package:magicmate_organizer/intro_Screen/addintro_screen.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/language/local_string.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'api_screens/data_store.dart';
import 'helpar/get_di.dart' as di;
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await GetStorage.init();
  await di.init();

  runApp(
    GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: onbording(),
      translations: LocaleString(),
      locale: getData.read("lan2") != null
          ? Locale(getData.read("lan2"), getData.read("lan1"))
          : Locale('en_US', 'en_US'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Flutter language file "local_string.dart"

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class LocaleString extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          "Add Wallet": "Add Wallet",
          "Wallet": "Wallet",
          "Your current Balance": "Your current Balance",
          "Add Amount": "Add Amount",
          "ADD": "ADD",
          "MagicMate": "Viacast Events",
          "My Booking": "My Ticket",
          "Fee": "IVA (22%)",
          "Cancle": "Cancel",
        },
        'et_EE': {
          "Profile": "Profiil",
          "Edit Profile": "Muuda profiili",
          "Notification": "Teavitused",
          "Language": "Keel",
          "Delete Account": "Kustuta konto",
          "Logout": "Väljun",
          "Are you sure you want to delete account?": "Oled sa kindel, et soovid konto kustutada?",
          "Cancel": "Tühistan",
          "Yes, Remove": "Jah, eemalda",
          "Are you sure you want to log out?": "Oled sa kindel, et soovid väljuda?",
          "Yes, Logout": "Jah, väljun",
          "Book Ticket Received!!": "Pilet kättesaadud!!",
          "Home": "Avaleht",
          "Booking            ": "Täna           ",
      }
      };

  String translateTitle(String title, String locale) {
    final translations = keys[locale];
    return translations != null && translations.containsKey(title)
        ? translations[title]!
        : title;
  }
}
```

Flutter "Home" tab file "Dashboard_screen.dart"

```
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Dashboard/Artist%20List/Artistlist_screen.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Dashboard/Coupons/Coupon_screen.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Dashboard/Coverimage%20screen/Coverimage_screen.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Dashboard/Event%20Gallery/Eventgallery_screen.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Dashboard/Event%20Types/Event_type.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Dashboard/Today_event/Todayevent_screen.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Dashboard/Event%20list/Eventlist_screen.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Dashboard/notificatin_screen.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Dashboard/payout/payout_screen.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Getx_controller.dart/Category_controller.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Getx_controller.dart/Dashboard_controller.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Getx_controller.dart/Eventtypeprice_controller.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Getx_controller.dart/Extra_image_controller.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Getx_controller.dart/Listofevent_controller.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Getx_controller.dart/Todayevent_controller.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/api_screens/confrigation.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/api_screens/data_store.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/utils/Colors.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/utils/Custom_widget.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/utils/Fontfamily.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class DashboardScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DashboardScreen> createState() => _DashboardScreenState();
}

class _DashboardScreenState extends State<DashboardScreen> {
  DashboardController dashboardController = Get.find();
  StatuswiseeventController statuswiseeventController = Get.find();
  ListofeventController listofeventController = Get.find();
  CategoryController categoryController = Get.find();
  EventtypepriceController eventtypepriceController = Get.find();
  CoverimageController coverimageController = Get.find();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dashboardController.dashboard();
    listofeventController.listofevent();
    categoryController.categorylist();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: bgcolor,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size(double.infinity, 60),
          child: AppBar(
            // automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: WhiteColor,
            leading: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 15, right: 5),
              child: Image.asset("assets/Logo1.png", height: 40, width: 40),
            ),
            title: Text(
              "${"Hey, "}" "${getData.read("UserLogin")["title"]}",
              maxLines: 1,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: FontFamily.gilroyExtraBold,
                color: appcolor,
                fontSize: 18,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
            actions: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Get.to(NotificationScreen(status: "1"));
                },
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    "assets/Notification.png",
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: RefreshIndicator(
          onRefresh: () {
            return Future.delayed(
              Duration(seconds: 2),
              () {
                setState(() {
                  dashboardController.dashboard();
                });
              },
            );
          },
          child: GetBuilder<DashboardController>(builder: (context) {
            return dashboardController.isLoading
                ? Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: Get.height,
                      width: Get.width,
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 25, top: 10),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              GridView.builder(
                                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                gridDelegate:
                                    SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                                  childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 12,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                                  mainAxisExtent: 100,
                                ),
                                itemCount: dashboardController
                                    .dashboardinfo?.reportData.length,
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  return InkWell(
                                    onTap: () async {
                                      switch (index) {
                                        case 0:
                                          setState(() {});
                                          listofeventController.listofevent();
                                          Get.to(() => Eventlistscreen());
                                          break;
                                        case 1:
                                          setState(() {});
                                          await statuswiseeventController
                                              .statuswiseevent(status: "Today");
                                          Get.to(() => Todayeventscreen(
                                            status: "Today event",
                                            hideStatus: "1",
                                          ));
                                          break;
                                        case 2:
                                          setState(() {});
                                          Get.to(() => Artistlistscreen());
                                          break;
                                        case 3:
                                          setState(() {});
                                          await statuswiseeventController
                                              .statuswiseevent(
                                              status: "Upcoming");
                                          Get.to(() => Todayeventscreen(
                                            status: "Upcoming event",
                                            hideStatus: "1",
                                          ));
                                          break;
                                        case 4:
                                          eventtypepriceController
                                              .eventtypeprice();
                                          Get.to(() => Eventtypescreen());
                                          break;
                                        case 5:
                                          setState(() {});
                                          await statuswiseeventController
                                              .statuswiseevent(status: "Past");
                                          Get.to(() => Todayeventscreen(
                                            status: "Past event",
                                            hideStatus: "1",
                                          ));
                                          break;
                                        case 6:
                                          coverimageController.coverimagelist();
                                          Get.to(() => Coverimagescreen());
                                          break;
                                        case 7:
                                          setState(() {});
                                          Get.to(() => Couponscreen());
                                          break;
                                        case 8:
                                          setState(() {});
                                          Get.to(() => Eventgalleryscreen());
                                          break;
                                        case 9:
                                          setState(() {});
                                          break;
                                        case 10:
                                          Get.to(MyPayoutScreen(status: "1"));
                                          break;
                                        case 11:
                                          break;
                                        default:
                                      }
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      height: 100,
                                      width: Get.size.width,
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                        color: WhiteColor,
                                      ),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: Get.size.width * 0.25,
                                            child: Column(
                                              mainAxisAlignment:
                                                  MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                index / 9 == 1 ||
                                                        index / 10 == 1 ||
                                                        index / 11 == 1
                                                    ? Text(
                                                        "${currency}${dashboardController.dashboardinfo?.reportData[index].reportData ?? ""}",
                                                        maxLines: 1,
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontFamily: FontFamily
                                                              .gilroyExtraBold,
                                                          color: BlackColor,
                                                          overflow: TextOverflow
                                                              .ellipsis,
                                                          fontSize: 24,
                                                        ),
                                                      )
                                                    : Text(
                                                        "${dashboardController.dashboardinfo?.reportData[index].reportData ?? ""}",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontFamily: FontFamily
                                                                .gilroyExtraBold,
                                                            color: BlackColor,
                                                            fontSize: 24),
                                                      ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                    height: Get.height * 0.010),
                                                Text(
                                                  dashboardController
                                                          .dashboardinfo
                                                          ?.reportData[index]
                                                          .title ??
                                                      "",
                                                  maxLines: 2,
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontFamily:
                                                        FontFamily.gilroyBold,
                                                    overflow:
                                                        TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                    fontSize: 15,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            width: 50,
                                            height: 50,
                                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                              image: DecorationImage(
                                                image: NetworkImage(
                                                    "${AppUrl.imageurl}${dashboardController.dashboardinfo?.reportData[index].url ?? ""}"),
                                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
          }),
        ));
  }
}
```

Flutter GetX Controller file for PHP "Dashboard_controller.dart"

```
// ignore_for_file: file_names, avoid_print, prefer_interpolation_to_compose_strings, unnecessary_brace_in_string_interps

import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Model%20class/Dashboardinfo_model.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Model%20class/Facility_Model.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/Model%20class/Restriction_model.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/api_screens/Api_werper.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/api_screens/confrigation.dart';
import 'package:magicmate_organizer/api_screens/data_store.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class DashboardController extends GetxController {
  bool isLoading = false;

  Dashboardinfo? dashboardinfo;
  FacilityInfo? facilityInfo;
  Restrictioninfo? restrictioninfo;

  String payOut = "";
  String nTitle = "";

  DashboardController() {
    dashboard();
  }

  dashboard() {
    var data = {
      "orag_id": getData.read("UserLogin")["id"],
    };
    print("===============dashboard=================${data}");
    ApiWrapper.dataPost(AppUrl.dashboard, data).then((val) {
      if ((val != null) && (val.isNotEmpty)) {
        if ((val['ResponseCode'] == "200") && (val['Result'] == "true")) {
          for (var element in val["report_data"]) {
            if (element["title"] == "Earning") {
              payOut = element["report_data"];
            }
          }
          dashboardinfo = Dashboardinfo.fromJson(val);
        } else {
          ApiWrapper.showToastMessage(val["ResponseMsg"]);
        }
        isLoading = true;
        update();
      }
    });
  }

  getFacilityList() async {
    try {
      isLoading = false;
      var data = {
        "orag_id": getData.read("UserLogin")["id"],
      };
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(AppUrl.baseUrl + AppUrl.facilitylist);
      var response = await http.post(uri, body: jsonEncode(data));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print("Result-------" + result.toString());
        facilityInfo = FacilityInfo.fromJson(result);
      }
      isLoading = true;
      update();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  getRestrictionList() async {
    try {
      isLoading = false;
      var data = {
        "orag_id": getData.read("UserLogin")["id"],
      };
      Uri uri = Uri.parse(AppUrl.baseUrl + AppUrl.restrictionlist);
      var response = await http.post(uri, body: jsonEncode(data));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
        print("Result-------" + result.toString());
        restrictioninfo = Restrictioninfo.fromJson(result);
      }
      isLoading = true;
      update();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

And last flutter file is model file "Dashboardinfo_model.dart"

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final dashboardinfo = dashboardinfoFromJson(jsonString);

// ignore_for_file: file_names

import 'dart:convert';

Dashboardinfo dashboardinfoFromJson(String str) =>
    Dashboardinfo.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dashboardinfoToJson(Dashboardinfo data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Dashboardinfo {
  String responseCode;
  String result;
  String responseMsg;
  List<ReportDatum> reportData;
  String withdrawLimit;

  Dashboardinfo({
    required this.responseCode,
    required this.result,
    required this.responseMsg,
    required this.reportData,
    required this.withdrawLimit,
  });

  factory Dashboardinfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Dashboardinfo(
        responseCode: json["ResponseCode"],
        result: json["Result"],
        responseMsg: json["ResponseMsg"],
        reportData: List<ReportDatum>.from(
            json["report_data"].map((x) => ReportDatum.fromJson(x))),
        withdrawLimit: json["withdraw_limit"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "ResponseCode": responseCode,
        "Result": result,
        "ResponseMsg": responseMsg,
        "report_data": List<dynamic>.from(reportData.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "withdraw_limit": withdrawLimit,
      };
}

class ReportDatum {
  String title;
  dynamic reportData;
  String url;

  ReportDatum({
    required this.title,
    required this.reportData,
    required this.url,
  });

  factory ReportDatum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ReportDatum(
        title: json["title"],
        reportData: json["report_data"],
        url: json["url"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "title": title,
        "report_data": reportData,
        "url": url,
      };
}
```

Comment: It seems there's too much code in this post. Please trim it down to a [mre]. If your question isn't about debugging, the code may not be needed at all.

Answer (score -1):

To implement multi-language support for titles fetched from a JSON request in your Flutter app, you can use the Flutter localization or a package like `get` for internationalization. Here's a general approach to translating the "Title" fields:

**Fetch and Store Titles**: When you fetch data from your PHP backend, store
To achieve multi-language support for dynamically fetched data in Flutter, you'll use a combination of localization in Flutter and translating the data when it's displayed in the UI. Here's a step-by-step approach with code examples:

**Set Up Localization in Flutter**:
First, ensure you have a localization setup in your Flutter project. If you're using the get package, you might already have something like this:

```dart
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class LocaleString extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
        'en_US': {
          "My Events": "My Events",
          // other translations...
        },
        'es_ES': {
          "My Events": "Mis Eventos",
          // other translations...
        },
        // Add other languages here...
      };

  String translateTitle(String title, String locale) {
    final translations = keys[locale];
    return translations != null && translations.containsKey(title)
        ? translations[title]!
        : title;
  }
}
```

**Fetch Data from PHP Backend**:
Assuming you're fetching data from your PHP backend, store the titles in their original language.

**Translate Titles in Flutter**:
When displaying a title in your UI, use the translation function to display it in the currently selected language. For example:

```dart
class DashboardScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final LocaleString localeString = LocaleString();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final locale = Localizations.localeOf(context).toString();
    // Assuming 'dashboardController.dashboardinfo?.reportData' holds your fetched data
    final reportData = dashboardController.dashboardinfo?.reportData ?? [];

    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: reportData.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = reportData[index];
        // Translate the title
        final translatedTitle = localeString.translateTitle(item.title, locale);

        return ListTile(
          title: Text(translatedTitle),
          // other widget properties...
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

In this code, `translateTitle` function from the `LocaleString` class is used to translate the title of each item in the fetched data. The current locale of the app is obtained using `Localizations.localeOf(context).toString()`.

This approach ensures that all titles fetched from your PHP backend are translated according to the app's current locale. Remember to maintain your translation keys in the `LocaleString` class as you add new titles or languages.

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi: [Why can't I use Artificial Intelligence tools to generate answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy)

Comment: Of course ChatGPT..it's totally pullshit :D